# Scheduler in android

Tags: android

I am creating a scheduler app in android which runs daily on user specified time here is the code please suggest why its not working

```
  private void setAlarm(String targetCal){
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Alarm Set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    String[] Time=targetCal.split(":");
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar timeOff = Calendar.getInstance();
    //int days = Calendar.SUNDAY + (7 - timeOff.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)); // how many days until Sunday
    timeOff.set(Calendar.HOUR,Integer.valueOf(Time[0].trim()));
    timeOff.set(Calendar.MINUTE,Integer.valueOf(Time[1].trim()));
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeOff.getTimeInMillis(), alarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY , pendingIntent);

}
```

Comment: any error in your log cat?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"

Comment: @RobinHood there is no error

Comment: @AleksG I mean there is no error in cat log and no activity on the specified time

Answer (score 1):

Replace `setRepeating` line with following:

*Try:-*

```
 alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeOff.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 60 * 60 * 24, pendingIntent);
```

*Instead:-*

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeOff.getTimeInMillis(), alarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY , pendingIntent);
```

Note: I just achieved this way and its works well fro me.